# How can i do crop multiple image in a batch

Tags: batch-file, photoshop, gimp, resize-crop

Is there any way so i can crop many picture by single command or is there any option in gimp or photoshop.

The things i know is images width is 930 and height is 800. i want to split those image into two new image width should equal to 930/2=465 where height should remain same.

Anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use ImageMagick, which is available for free for Windows, Linux and OSX from [here](http://www.imagemagick.org)

For example, to crop all jpegs in current directory to 256 pixels max by 256 pixels max

```
mogrify -resize 256x256 *.jpg
```

For your purposes, assuming an input file is called `a.jpg`, you probably need

```
convert  a.jpg -crop 465x800+465+0 +repage a2.jpg
convert  a.jpg -crop 465x800+0+0 +repage a1.jpg
```

and a1.jpg and a2.jpg will be the two halves,

I don't know if you are on Windows or Linux, but you can put this in a loop easily enough to do all your images

**Untested:**

Linux...

```
for f in *.jpg
do
    newbase=$(basename "$f")
    convert "$f" -crop 465x800+465+0 +repage "${newbase}_1.jpg"
    convert "$f" -crop 465x800+0+0 +repage "${newbase}_2.jpg"
done
```

MS-DOS Command (my skills are rusty here)

```
FOR %a in (*.jpg) DO something
```

Back up your images before you try any commands!!!

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a folder with images (recursive), just images, no other files...
Assuming all these images are large enough to split...
you can use this script

I'm using this to split 3840x1080 images into 2 1920x1080 images for dual screen desktop background images.

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$(find -type f)
basedir=$(pwd)

width=1920 
height=1080

for f in $files
do
        dir=$(dirname "$f")
        cd $dir

        file=$(basename "$f")
        newfile=$(echo $file | cut -d. -f1)

        convert "$file" -crop ${width}x${height}+0+0 +repage "${newfile}_1_of_2.jpg"
        convert "$file" -crop ${width}x${height}+${width}+0 +repage "${newfile}_2_of_2.jpg"

        cd $basedir
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [***`crop.bat`***](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/imageProcessing/crop.bat) (does not require external binaries):

```
call crop.bat -source image.jpg -target image-left.jpg  -percentage yes -right 50 -force yes

call crop.bat -source image.jpg -target image-right.jpg  -percentage yes -left 50 -force yes
```

For mass image cropping you can check the [***`for`***](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) command.